# Data returned for autocomplete are not formatted in a json list correctly

Tags: python, flask

My autocomplete view is matching users correctly, however the two users are returned as the same result, so I can't select one or the other to autocomplete.  It also returns the object name, not just the user name.  For example, it will return `<User 'kinwolf'>, <User 'kintest'>` as a string instead of simply the `kinwolf, kintest`.  How do I get my view to return the usernames in the correct json format so autocomplete works?

```python
@main.route('/list-members',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
@admin_required
def find_member():
    form = Find_member()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        username = form.member_name.data
        return redirect(url_for('.member',username=username))
    return render_template('members_list.html',form=form)

#This route is a callback for the JQueryautocomplete
@main.route('/autocomplete',methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    search = request.args.get('term')
    members = User.query.filter(User.firstname.like('%'+search+'%')).all()
    member_list=str(members) #need to do this because it returns a value that is not JSONable
#     print (member_list[member])
    return jsonify(json_list=member_list)

class Find_member(Form):
    member_name = StringField('Type the member full name:', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Search')
```

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}Project-Z{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1> Members list </h1>

    <h2>Find a member</h2>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#member_name" ).autocomplete({
            source: '{{url_for("main.autocomplete")}}',
            minLength: 2,
        });
    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You probably want something like `members_list = [m.first_name for m in members]`. You could also use a query that only returns the first name rather than all fields.

Comment: Thanks, that change allowed me to get the name only(['John Doe', 'Jane Doe'] instead of the user object  <User 'kinwolf'>, <User 'kintest'> like before.

But I still get both as a single string, so I can't actually select one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research I saw another post that used another method to jsonify a list.  I tried it and it worked, I now receive the list in the web form correctly and I can select the user I want to autocomplete.

The line is

```
 from flask import Response, json
 return Response(json.dumps(member_list,),mimetype='application/json')
```

instead of

```
return jsonify(json_list=member_list)
```

I read that the reason that we can't pass a list through jsonify anymore is for security reasons, sadly.